# Do Optionals default to nil?

Tags: swift

What is the initial value of the `delegate` variable if no constructor is provided?

```
class Example {
    weak var delegate: Bool?
}
```

Comment: If you haven't declared the type of protocol as class: `protocol Bool: class { }` you'll also get this error: `'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'Bool'`

Comment: Sorry that was just me filling in `Bool` to replace a protocol-driven class. You're right!

Comment: You can easily print(delegate) and check what's the output...

Comment: @AhmadF Sometimes things behave differently on different systems. It's nice to have the information from the horse's mouth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is automatically set to nil if unassigned.

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309):

> If you define an optional variable without providing a default value,
>   the variable is automatically set to nil for you

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
   class Survey {
        var  text : String = ""
        var response : String?
        init(text:String) {
            self.text = text
        }
        func ask(){
            print("The text is \(text) and the response is \(response!)" )
        }
    }
    var sur = Survey(text: "what is your fav sport")

    sur.response = "my fav sport is cricket"
    sur.ask()
    //print("\(sur.response)")
```