# Are local variables in Swift implicitly initialised to nil when used with UnsafeMutablePointer?

Tags: swift, initialization, memory-corruption, unsafemutablepointer, memory-safety

```
var cgImage: CGImage?
VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer,
                                 options: nil,
                                 imageOut: &cgImage)
return cgImage
```

[VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/videotoolbox/1536089-vtcreatecgimagefromcvpixelbuffer)() takes in an UnsafeMutalePointer. Suppose an error occurs and it doesn't assign to cgImage. Is there a chance that I'll be returning an uninitialised variable? If so, I need to initialise the variable with nil:

```
var cgImage: CGImage? = nil
```

This is not a dupe of [Do Optionals default to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907002/do-optionals-default-to-nil) because this question talks of UnsafeMutablePointers, and concerns local variables while that question talks of properties.

Comment: The Swift *compiler*  would complain if `cgImage` is used without being initialized.

Comment: Not with UnsafeMutablePointer, right? Its documentation points out that it can work with unitialised memory. This question is not a dupe as I pointed out in the updated description. Reopen the question.

Comment: There is no difference between `var cgImage: CGImage?` and `var cgImage: CGImage? = nil`, as pointed out in the other thread.